# Using office 365 as a identify provider

Tags: office365, identity, saml-2.0

There is an application which we want to use it by using our Office 365 account. We found out that you can login into the application using different identity providers such as Facebook, Twitter, Google,... However we want to make it possible for our Office 365 users login and use this third party application. The owner of this third party application said that the application accepts only SAML 2.0. My question is what do I need to do to make our Office 365 act as a identify provider? They are going to develop a page for us and add a button to make it possible for our users that choose to log in using their office 365 account. I think, I am not so sure that when our users browse to the page and click the button, a SAML 2.0 token must be created (based on the office 365 account) to be able to login and use the application, in the same way you choose to log in using your Facebook account. Please help me to understand the concept and solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O365 sits on top of Azure AD so what you really need is to see if that application is in the [Azure AD gallery](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/active-directory/all/) and then use that for SAML SSO.

Comment: Thanks nzpcmad, how do I add the application which is not ours to our Azure AD gallery? And how do I use that for SAML SSO?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-app-gallery-listing/ and it appears in the Access Panel http://windowsitpro.com/windows-azure/windows-azure-active-directory-strengthens-its-idaas-appeal-access-panel

Comment: Or manual - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-saas-custom-apps/

Comment: As soon as I click on "Add an unlisted application your organization is using", it redirects me to this page https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-saas-custom-apps/ . Does it means that I haven't Active Directory Premium? Is there any workaround to test the third party application if it works, without upgradeing my Azure AD to Premium?

Comment: No you need AAD Premium to follow this route. You can always get a one month trial and see how you go.